# break and return @temp_catid if(true)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, scripting, sql-scripts

i have a following sql function which takes a string word as input it then checks whether the word is equal to a categoryName  or not i want it to behave like when the if statement is true it breaks from the loop and return @temp_catid else it returns 0 or 1 how can i do that im new to sql scripting plz help... below is my function

```
USE [myDB]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[udfisEqualToCategory]    Script Date: 01/31/2011 10:57:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




Create FUNCTION [dbo].[udfisEqualToCategory](@word nvarchar(max))
RETURNS INT

AS
BEGIN
--declare a temp category table for data processing
declare @temptbl_category Table
(
indexx int identity(1,1),
categoryid int,
categoryname nvarchar(max)
)
--insert data from feedcrawler.category into temp category table
insert into @temptbl_category 
select CategoryId,Name
from Category

--declare some variables to hold the data of current row of temp category table being processed while looping

declare @temp_catid int
declare @temp_catname nvarchar(max)
declare @rowcount int
set @rowcount=(select count(indexx)from @temptbl_category)



declare @I int
set @I=1

--print'given string-> '+ @FullName
--print'string length-> '+convert(nvarchar(max),@strlen)
while(@I <= @rowcount)
begin

select @temp_catname=categoryname,@temp_catid=categoryid from @temptbl_category where indexx=@I
set @temp_catname=lower(@temp_catname)
if(@word=@temp_catname) 
begin
return @temp_catid
break
end--end if

set @I=@I+1

END--while loop ends
return 0
end-- function ends

GO
```

Comment: i know omitting punctuation saves my time when im typing but takes others time when they read it no offends just an observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop, just search the table with WHERE

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[udfisEqualToCategory](@word nvarchar(max))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @temp_catid int

    select
        @temp_catid = categoryid
    from
        Category
    WHERE
        LOWER(@word) = LOWER(categoryname);

    --no match = @temp_catid IS NULL. So change to zero
    RETURN ISNULL(@temp_catid, 0);
END
GO
```